# Conversion of Binary Float

Tags: python

Given a Binary Float string containing a fractional part `s: 100.0011`

output must be `4.1875`

i used `".".join(map(lambda x:str(int(x,2)),s.split('.')))`

this gives `4.3` but not `4.1875`

Comment: Remove the decimal point, convert it to an int with `int(x, 2)`, then rescale it based on where the decimal point was?

Comment: @user2357112 i did that but that is wrong. since 0011 is 3 . but answer is 1875

Comment: You should read up on [binary representation of real numbers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representing_real_numbers).

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар: That's not removing the decimal point; that's splitting on the decimal point. I mean like `int(s.replace('.', ''), 2)`.

Comment: @user2357112 that gives 67 as answer

Comment: 0011 is 3 in base 2 . Why would it be 1875?

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар yes, you missed the rescaling step

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is rescaling. can please explain :)

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар adjusting the value to account for the decimal point. Just read that Wikipedia article, it explains how these numbers work.

Comment: @omu_negru 100.0011 is 2**3 + 2**-3 + 2**-4 = 8 + 0.125 + 0.0625 = 8.1875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the number into whole and fractional sections, then use `int` to make each part decimal, keeping in mind that the *fractional* section has to be adjusted depending on its length:

```
>>> s = "100.0011"

>>> d = s.split(".")

>>> int(d[0],2) + float(int(d[1],2)) / 2**len(d[1])
4.1875
```

Dividing the `0011` by two the the power of its length (2<sup>4</sup> is 16) ensures that it's treated correctly (<sup>3</sup>/<sub>16</sub> is 0.1875).

Comment: `bin` isn't used here. Did you mean to say something else?

Comment: @user2357112: yes, sorry, I got it right in the code but wrong in the text. Fixed now, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to a decimal with this code. Not the most efficient, but works:

```
s = "100.0011" # binary number
n = s.index(".") # number of positions before the decimal point
r = 0 # result

for digit in s.replace(".", ""): # iterate through each digit ommiting the point '.'
    r += int(digit) * 2 ** (n-1) # multiplicate the digit by the respective power of 2
    n -= 1

print r # 4.1875
```

**How does this work?** Remember how you convert a binary number into a decimal (base 10):

```
100.0011  -> 1       0       0   .   0          0          1          1
powerOf 2 ->    4       2       1      1/2        1/4        1/8        1/16
                |       |       |       |          |          |          |
             1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0 + 0*2^(-1) + 0*2^(-2) + 1*2^(-3) + 1*2^(-4)
```

Comment: Note that `len(s.split(".")[0]) == s.index(".")`, and you could use `zip` and `range` to factor out the manual incrementing of `n`

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for pointing it out. I will edit it tomorrow. Sleep time :)

Answer (score -1):

`int(x,2)` isn't going to understand how to convert the fractional part of the decimal, since those values are all powers of negative 2 rather than positive 2. You can do something like the following:

```
int_, frac = s.split(".")
res = ((int(int_, 2) << len(frac)) + int(frac, 2)) / (2 ** len(frac))
```

Comment: That gives the answer as 4

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that >> rounded off floats. It's fixed and now gives the correct answer.